# How to treat function as string?

Tags: c#

just I want to ask is it possible to Call function as `ToUpper` or `ToLower()` as string   for example `f.Name.Replace(" ", "_").ToLower()".ToLower()"` or `"ToUpper"` for example if user select convert file name to ToLower() from dropdown list.it will take the value 'ToLower' and added to in of the function and executed the function call

Comment: are you asking if you can call a method by specifying the name of the method as a string?  If so, yes, via reflection.

Comment: Reflection may be way OTT, and a simple switch statement on some enum may be more appropriate.

Comment: in addition, reflection is expensive.

Comment: but why reflection is expensive?

Comment: Reflection breaks security, and it requires various lookups, all things that make it slow. If you really really need reflection, and you need to do it often, you can use a compromise solution where you use reflection to build a method (which calls the actual method you want) and create a delegate to that method. Then you only have the cost of a delegate call, which is vastly lower. Expression trees in are a very easy way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, not cleanly.  You could use reflection to find the method but you'd have to know the exact type that the function will be applied to since you won't get sophisticated binding like you do at compile-time.  Plus you'll be limited to one method signature (in this case, no input parameters and returns a string).

To support any string function with that signature you could use:

```
string val = f.Name.Replace(" ", "_").ToLower();

string strCommand = "ToUpper";
MethodInfo theMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod(strCommand,new Type[] {});
string result = (string)(theMethod.Invoke(val,null));
```

But a simple `switch` seems cleaner and safer here.

Comment: Cleaner, safer, and of course, you can't run reflection outside of FullTrust.

Answer (score 1):

The [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ty67wk28.aspx) (`?:`) would probably be a better option here

```
var fileName = f.Name.Replace(" ", "_");
fileName = ddl.SelectedValue == "ToLower" ? fileName.ToLower() : fileName.ToUpper();
```

Using Reflection for something as trivial as this is pretty unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a defined dictionary of functions, which you can access by name of the action. You will get rid of any conditional statements and of all reflection. Example is given below:

```
var actions = new Dictionary<string, Func<string, string>>()
              {
                    //keys may have other, human-readable values
                    {"ToLower", s => s.ToLower()}, 
                    {"ToUpper", s => s.ToUpper()}
              };

//you will receive this from drop down list, it's the name of the action
var userSelectedOption = "ToUpper"; 

//string that you want to process
var myString = "some other user input";

//selecting appropriate action and passing myString to it
var transformedString = actions[userSelectedOption](myString);

//prints "SOME OTHER USER INPUT"
Console.WriteLine(transformedString);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the methods you want to call before, you can register them in a dictionary (key = name of the function or something user friendly, value = function that performs the conversion):

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, Func<string, string>>();
dict.Add("Lowercase", x => x.ToLower());
dict.Add("Uppercase", x => x.ToUpper());
```

You can bind the drop down list to the dictionary (text = Key, value = Value) and perform the conversion as follows (ddl is the name of the DropDownList):

```
var f = (Func<string, string>)ddl.SelectedValue;
var convStr = f(inputStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection, you can call a methods using a string:

```
String ToLower =  "ToLower";
String SometString = "This Is My String";

Type stringType = typeof(String);

// Get the overload of ToLower that takes no parameters
MethodInfo method = stringType.GetMethod(ToLower, System.Type.EmptyTypes);

// Invoke the method with no parameters
String newString = (String)method.Invoke(SometString, null);
MessageBox.Show(newString);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, you want to call a method based on a string.

You can use reflection, which is a topic in and of itself, but to get you started you can do something like:

```
MethodInfo chosenMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod(methodName, Types.EmptyTypes);
chosenMethod.Invoke(stringToModify, new object[]{});
```

But if it is a very limited set of functions you want to expose, you should just do a switch statement over the user input:

```
switch(methodName)
{
    case "ToLower":
         stringToModify.ToLower();
         break;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `switch` statement:

```
switch (value) // Assuming value is of type SomeEnum
{
   case SomeEnum.ToLower:
      return f.ToLower()
   case SomeEnum.ToUpper:
      return f.ToUpper();
   default:
      //Do the Default
      break;
}
```

This is how you parse what you get from the UI:

```
public static T ParseEnum<T>( string value )
{
    return (T) Enum.Parse( typeof( T ), value, true );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might need to avoid limitations is sort of a **Runtime intepreter of C#**, like `eval()` function in JavaScript, which is not easily nor trivial to implement, but there is a good library out there called **C# Eval** ( http://csharp-eval.com/Download.php ) that uses Reflection internally of course. It is heavier but more effective for this, or even for much more complex escenarios.
You might use it in this way for example:

```
class Person
{
  public string Name;

  public string Process(string expression)
  {
    return CsEval.Eval(this, expression);
  }
}
```

And then might call it:

```
var f = new Person();
f.Name = "John";
f.Name = f.Process("Name.Replace(" ", "_").ToLower()");
```

Of course this is just an example of how it evaluate what is in the string, as you can see you just need to pass a "context" where the expression is going to mean something, which in this case is the current class ("this").